# saving video/images to MongoDB in NodeJS server by using GridFS

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am looking for a sample example for storing videos/images in `MongoDB` using `GridFS`. I came across [this official site](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle2.html) and followed the below code snippet

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Grid = mongo.Grid;
// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(err) return console.dir(err);
  var grid = new Grid(db, 'fs');
  var buffer = new Buffer("Hello world");
  grid.put(buffer, {metadata:{category:'text'}, content_type: 'text'}, function(err, fileInfo) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log("Finished writing file to Mongo");
    }
  });
});
```

When I run the code I am getting bellow error

```
Grid = mongo.Grid;
       ^
ReferenceError: mongo is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Rahul\Nodejs\Fileupload\fileupload\Samples\grid-fs
\mongo.js:3:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
at startup (node.js:117:18)
at node.js:951:3
```

please share any link for How to store files in MongoDB using GridFS in Nodejs.

**EDIT 1**

I tried a lot to get it work and finally I come to know the interface `Grid` is removed from `Mongodb 2.1` so It won't work but there is no documentation for the replacement of Grid. Now I don't have clear idea about which one to use i.e `GridStore`, `GridFSBucket`, etc

Is this documentation misleading?

Comment: Hate to state the obvious, is `mongo` defined?  i bet it isn't.

Comment: @BanksySan I dont have any idea what kind of reference is that, i took it as it is from site, can you please post the answer if you know that

Comment: It's telling you that the variable `mongo`, on line 3 is undefined.  Can't be more explicit than that.

Comment: thank you @BanksySan, I just want to know where mongo variable should point, like var mongo = require('mongodb');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
```

The things off the `require('mongodb'}`:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');
```

From the documentation [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html).

Comment: Thank for the answer I tried this and got Grid is not a function